# Django - Add a field to a form that not should be in a model

Tags: django, forms, model

I have a form based on a model, but I want to add one more field. That field should not be on the model (or it can be, but I don't want it to have a column and be saved on the database).

This field will be passed to the view and will define what action the view will take (will be used on an if on the view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional fields to a ModelForm:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    extra_stuff = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['bar', 'biz']
```

Comment: Great, worked just fine. One more question, how can i change the order  of the fields? I want this added field to appear first, and it is appearing last, after the model fields.

Thanks again